# measuring with openlayers api does not give accurate value

Tags: gis, openlayers, coordinate-systems, units-of-measurement

my problem is that measured length or area with openlayers api has difference with the real one, for example a 55.30 meter length is 50.13 m in my web app.  my data are in "projected UTM WGS84 Zone 40" coordinate system and I am using openlayers js api v:"7.5.1" in react. Thanks in advance.
Note 1: base on openlayers documents, geometry.getLength() and geometry.getArea() methods return measures of projected (planar) geometries.
// this is a part of defined map in CreateMap component:

```
useEffect(() => { if(mapRef.current) {
  const centerUTM = [253610, 2867476]  
  const map = new Map({
    target: mapRef.current,
    layers: [
      new TileLayer({
       //source: new OSM(),  
      }),
    ],
    view: new View({
      projection: "EPSG:32640",
      center: centerUTM, 
      zoom: 20, // Initial zoom level
    }),
  })
  props.setMap(map)
  return () => {
    map.setTarget(null)
  }
}}, [])
```

// follow is part of my GeometryCalculate to measure a length or area:

```
const source = new VectorSource();
  const vector = new VectorLayer({
      source: source,
      style: vectorStyle,
  });
  
  vectorLayersRef.current.push(vector);
  map.addLayer(vector);
   
  draw = new Draw({
      source: source,
      type: drawingType,
      stopClick: true,
  });

  let sketch;
   
  let tooltipCoord;
   
  draw.on('drawstart', (evt) => {
    setIsDrawing(true); // Set isDrawing to true when drawing starts
     // Create a new measure tooltip element
    const measureTooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
    measureTooltipElement.className = 'ol-tooltip ol-tooltip-measure';

    // Create a new measure tooltip overlay
    const measureTooltip = new Overlay({
      element: measureTooltipElement,
      offset: [0, -15],
      positioning: 'bottom-center',
      stopEvent: false,
      insertFirst: false,
    });

    // Add the measure tooltip overlay to the map
    map.addOverlay(measureTooltip);
    
    sketch = evt.feature;        
    
    sketch.getGeometry().on('change', function (evt) {
      const geom = evt.target;
      let output;
      if (geom instanceof Polygon) {
        output = formatArea(geom);
        tooltipCoord = geom.getInteriorPoint().getCoordinates();
      } else if (geom instanceof LineString) {
        output = formatLength(geom);
        tooltipCoord = geom.getLastCoordinate();
      }
        measureTooltipElement.innerHTML = output;
        measureTooltip.setPosition(tooltipCoord);
    });
  });

  draw.on('drawend', () => {
    setIsDrawing(false); // Set isDrawing to false when drawing ends
  });
  map.addInteraction(draw); 
  drawInteractionRef.current = draw; 

  const formatLength = function (line) {
    const length = getLength(line);
     
    let output;
    if (length > 100) {
      output = `${Math.round((length / 1000) * 100) / 100} km`;
    } else {
      output = `${Math.round(length * 100) / 100} m`;
    }
    return output;
  };

  const formatArea = function (polygon) {
    const area = getArea(polygon);
    let output;
    if (area > 10000) {
      output = `${Math.round((area / 1000000) * 100) / 100} km²`;
    } else {
      output = `${Math.round(area * 100) / 100} m²`;
    }
    return output;
  };
```

Comment: The spherical getArea and getLength methods default to using web mercator coordinates https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_sphere.html  If you are using a different projection you must specify that in the options https://codesandbox.io/s/measure-forked-vsnxdf?file=/main.js  In a UTM projection the geometry.getLength() and geometry.getArea() methods should give a similar result.